# i cant put 1 selection it keeps adding both wheels

Tags: mesh, rigging

hey guys so im trying to do a rig car on this vehicle but im trying to add one wheel as a selection it seems that this vehicle has mirror on but everytime i go to edit mode went for the front wheel press L to put it as one selection but it keeps adding both wheel as a selection i need one selection on everywheel , thanks for the help [image]

Comment: Hello could you please share the wheel object? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=eQgDEBkQ" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/eQgDEBkQ/)

Comment: You are in Object mode, if you select your object it will also select its mirrored image, switch to Edit mode if you want to select the original mesh only

Comment: yes i did went to edit mode and select only object but my question is im trying to ctrl p to add one selection only one wheel but i cant its mirroring and i cant ctrl p selection on if u know what i mean

Comment: What operation are you trying to do with Ctrl P?

Comment: im trying to add selection to rig a car so i can rig every wheel front wheel L front wheel R and back etc

Comment: if each wheel needs to be independent you need to apply the Mirror modifier

Comment: thank you it works , even tho blender is very complicated yet my favourite i have been using blender for 7 month and im still having some problem with it but thank you

Comment: Actually what ypu could do is make some linked duplications of your wheel, so that any change on one of them is replicated on the others